# Changes to collection do not update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I don't understand why when I update a object, my bound controls do not update.

The data displays fine initially, but when I want to refresh the data displayed in the UI nothing happens when I update the object. The object updates fine. The ViewModel does use INotifyPropertyChanged on all fields.

However if I update individual items directly, I can update my UI. As commented below.

I guess I've made a school boy error somewhere here?

UPDATE: I've added the model to the question. While I understand the answers, I don't understand how to implement it. Attempted to implement a collection changed event without success. Can I have some pointers please?

```
        public partial class CisArrivalsPanel : UserControl
            {
                private ApiDataArrivalsDepartures _theArrivalsDepartures;

                public CisArrivalsPanel()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    _theArrivalsDepartures = new ApiDataArrivalsDepartures();

                    _theArrivalsDepartures = MakeQuery.LiveTrainArrivals("London Kings Cross");

                    this.DataContext = _theArrivalsDepartures;

                    ListBoxArr.ItemsSource = _theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList;            
                }


                void Reload()
                {

//This does not update the UI**

                    _theArrivalsDepartures = MakeQuery.LiveTrainArrivals("London Paddington");

//However this (when uncommented, and I comment out the above line) does update the UI**

                    //_theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList[0].OriginName = "test";
                    //_theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList[0].Platform = "0";
                    //_theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList[0].BestArrivalEstimateMins = "999";
                    //_theArrivalsDepartures.StationName = "test";
                }


                private void StationHeader_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
                {
                    Reload();

                    Debug.WriteLine(_theArrivalsDepartures.StationName);
                    foreach (var a in _theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(a.OriginName);
                        Debug.WriteLine(a.BestArrivalEstimateMins);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**EDIT : Added Model**

```
public class ApiDataArrivalsDepartures : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _stationName;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "station_name")]
        public string StationName {
            get
            {
                return _stationName;
            }
            set
            {
                _stationName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StationName");
            } 
        }

       private List<StationListOfMovements> _stationMovementList;

        public List<StationListOfMovements> StationMovementList
        {
            get
            {
                return _stationMovementList;
            }
            set
            {
                _stationMovementList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StationMovementList");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }



 public class StationListOfMovements : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private string _originName;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "origin_name")]
        public string OriginName {
            get
            {
                return _originName;
            }
            set
            {
                _originName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("OriginName");
            } 
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "destination_name")]
        public string DestinationName { get; set; }

        private string _platform;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Platform")]
        public string Platform {
            get
            {
                return _platform;
            }
            set
            {
                _platform = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Platform");
            }
        }


        private string _bestArrivalEstimateMins;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "best_arrival_estimate_mins")]
        public string BestArrivalEstimateMins {
            get
            {
                return _bestArrivalEstimateMins;
            }
            set
            {
                _bestArrivalEstimateMins = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("BestArrivalEstimateMins");
            } 
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of StationMovementList? It appears to be some type of Collection, does the collection implement INotifyCollectionChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pieces here pertaining to your collection (technically three):

1. If you want a **new** collection to propagate, the collection property has to raise `PropertyChanged` (sounds like it does)
2. If you want **add/remove** on the collection to propagate, you need to use a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. `ObservableCollection` is a good choice.
3. If you want changes **to the items in the container** to propagate, then *those* items need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Make sure all those are covered, and the changes should appear on the UI as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `DataContext` and `ItemsSource` too.

```
void Reload()
{

  //This does not update the UI**

   _theArrivalsDepartures = MakeQuery.LiveTrainArrivals("London Paddington");
   DataContext = theArrivalsDepartures;
   ListBoxArr.ItemsSource = _theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList;
}
```

Comment: Ugh... reassigning the `DataContext` doesn't sound like a good thing to do on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Use for the collection ObservableCollection , this class notify the ui when change to the collection occurred 
your reload function works because the there is PropertyChanged on all the fields include this one 
it notify the ui and reload the correct collection

Comment: Not quite, it works because it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. It *also* implements and uses `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but it isn't as relevant, and I'm honestly not sure if it needs it for anything.